# How to block advertisements using Awesomium in WinForms?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, event-handling, awesomium, adblock

This issue contains a couple of issues regarding use of Awesomium 1.7.4.2 for WinForms on Visual Studio 2012 using VB.NET as the host language and x86 release mode on framework 4.0 / 4.5

1. Click events, etc, do not fire.
2. Lots of "unhandled exception" messages from javascripts trying to open windows, etc.
3. Advertisements are not blockable (or do not seem to be)

I would like to gain control over this control to be able to tell it simple commands which I am able to do with the horrifying control (IE WebView). Basically, I want to be able to do the following :

1. Detect when a user "clicks" a link (by keypress, also by mouse click, also by touch), and intercept it using code in the .NET application.
2. I wish to completely block Javascript from redirecting the browser on click or otherwise.
3. I wish to prevent meta-refresh redirects.
4. I would like to have access to the source, and modify it before it is rendered in the WebView -- For example, remove certain blots of code -- However, I do not wish to load the source locally. This means that I do not wish to obtain the source from the site, and set the view to a file/memory containing that source without actually BEING on that site. The webbrowser must be Navigated to the site, using that sites cookies/sessions/etc.

I have this simple snippet which took a while to figure out, and it seems to show the events that actually ARE firing, however, not sure how to send back a "do not complete this command", in the event of types like "popup".

What would be super cool, is if I could load a crx file as an addon since this is a native Chrome browser component --- the addon being  "AdBlock Plus" of course, which would then handle all the advertisement blocking and such. And then I would just have to deal with handling popup windows -- not the inline advertisement crap.

```
    Public Class Form1

        Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            WebControl1.Source = New Uri("http://vidbull.com/k1ie8l9kchme.html")
        End Sub

        Private Sub WebControl1_ConsoleMessage(sender As Object, e As Awesomium.Core.ConsoleMessageEventArgs) Handles WebControl1.ConsoleMessage
            If WebControl1.HasTargetURL = True And e.EventType = Awesomium.Core.WebViewEventType.ConsoleMessage And e.LineNumber = 1 Then
                WebControl1.Source = WebControl1.TargetURL
            End If

            If e.EventName = "popup" Then

            End If
            Debug.Print(e.EventName & " - " & e.Message & " - " & e.EventType & " - " & e.LineNumber)
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Here is a sample output from the console loading this page.

```
ConsoleMessage - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null - 15 - 166
ConsoleMessage - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://vidbull.com/k1ie8l9kchme.html from frame with URL http://cdn.adnotch.com/www/delivery/afr.php?zoneid=27&target=_blank. Domains, protocols and ports must match. - 15 - 1
ConsoleMessage - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://vidbull.com/k1ie8l9kchme.html from frame with URL http://cdn.adnotch.com/www/delivery/afr.php?zoneid=27&target=_blank. Domains, protocols and ports must match.   - 15 - 1
ConsoleMessage - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://vidbull.com/k1ie8l9kchme.html from frame with URL http://cdn.adnotch.com/www/delivery/afr.php?zoneid=27&target=_blank. Domains, protocols and ports must match.   - 15 - 1
ConsoleMessage - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://vidbull.com/k1ie8l9kchme.html from frame with URL http://cdn.adnotch.com/www/delivery/afr.php?zoneid=27&target=_blank. Domains, protocols and ports must match.   - 15 - 1
ConsoleMessage - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://vidbull.com/k1ie8l9kchme.html from frame with URL http://cdn.adnotch.com/www/delivery/afr.php?zoneid=27&target=_blank. Domains, protocols and ports must match.   - 15 - 1
ConsoleMessage - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://vidbull.com/k1ie8l9kchme.html from frame with URL http://cdn.adnotch.com/www/delivery/afr.php?zoneid=27&target=_blank. Domains, protocols and ports must match.   - 15 - 1
ConsoleMessage - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://vidbull.com/k1ie8l9kchme.html from frame with URL http://cdn.adnotch.com/www/delivery/afr.php?zoneid=27&target=_blank. Domains, protocols and ports must match.   - 15 - 1
ConsoleMessage - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://vidbull.com/k1ie8l9kchme.html from frame with URL http://cdn.adnotch.com/www/delivery/afr.php?zoneid=27&target=_blank. Domains, protocols and ports must match.   - 15 - 1
ConsoleMessage - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://vidbull.com/k1ie8l9kchme.html from frame with URL http://cdn.adnotch.com/www/delivery/afr.php?zoneid=27&target=_blank. Domains, protocols and ports must match.   - 15 - 1
ConsoleMessage - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://vidbull.com/k1ie8l9kchme.html from frame with URL http://cdn.adnotch.com/www/delivery/afr.php?zoneid=27&target=_blank. Domains, protocols and ports must match.   - 15 - 1
```

And when you "click" on the page anywhere (no hyperlink areas)

```
ConsoleMessage - Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLHtmlElement> has no method 'webkitRequestFullscreen' - 15 - 1
ConsoleMessage - event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future. - 15 - 1
ConsoleMessage - event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future. - 15 - 1
```

And when you "click" on the "Continue to Video" link

```
    ConsoleMessage - Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLHtmlElement> has no method 'webkitRequestFullscreen' - 15 - 1
    ConsoleMessage - event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future. - 15 - 1
    ConsoleMessage - event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future. - 15 - 1
    ConsoleMessage - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null - 15 - 166
    ConsoleMessage - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://vidbull.com/k1ie8l9kchme.html from frame with URL http://cdn.adnotch.com/www/delivery/afr.php?zoneid=31&target=_blank. Domains, protocols and ports must match. - 15 - 1
    ConsoleMessage - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://vidbull.com/k1ie8l9kchme.html from frame with URL http://cdn.adnotch.com/www/delivery/afr.php?zoneid=29&target=_blank. Domains, protocols and ports must match. - 15 - 1
    ConsoleMessage - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://vidbull.com/k1ie8l9kchme.html from frame with URL http://cdn.adnotch.com/www/delivery/afr.php?zoneid=31&target=_blank. Domains, protocols and ports must match. - 15 - 1
    ConsoleMessage - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://vidbull.com/k1ie8l9kchme.html from frame with URL http://cdn.adnotch.com/www/delivery/afr.php?zoneid=31&target=_blank. Domains, protocols and ports must match. - 15 - 1
    ConsoleMessage - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://vidbull.com/k1ie8l9kchme.html from frame with URL http://cdn.adnotch.com/www/delivery/afr.php?zoneid=29&target=_blank. Domains, protocols and ports must match. - 15 - 1
    ConsoleMessage - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://vidbull.com/k1ie8l9kchme.html from frame with URL http://cdn.adnotch.com/www/delivery/afr.php?zoneid=29&target=_blank. Domains, protocols and ports must match. - 15 - 1
    ConsoleMessage - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://vidbull.com/k1ie8l9kchme.html from frame with URL http://cdn.adnotch.com/www/delivery/afr.php?zoneid=31&target=_blank. Domains, protocols and ports must match. - 15 - 1
    ConsoleMessage - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://vidbull.com/k1ie8l9kchme.html from frame with URL http://cdn.adnotch.com/www/delivery/afr.php?zoneid=31&target=_blank. Domains, protocols and ports must match. - 15 - 1
    ConsoleMessage - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://vidbull.com/k1ie8l9kchme.html from frame with URL http://cdn.adnotch.com/www/delivery/afr.php?zoneid=31&target=_blank. Domains, protocols and ports must match. - 15 - 1
    ConsoleMessage - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://vidbull.com/k1ie8l9kchme.html from frame with URL http://cdn.adnotch.com/www/delivery/afr.php?zoneid=31&target=_blank. Domains, protocols and ports must match. - 15 - 1
    ConsoleMessage - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://vidbull.com/k1ie8l9kchme.html from frame with URL http://cdn.adnotch.com/www/delivery/afr.php?zoneid=31&target=_blank. Domains, protocols and ports must match. - 15 - 1
    ConsoleMessage - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://vidbull.com/k1ie8l9kchme.html from frame with URL http://cdn.adnotch.com/www/delivery/afr.php?zoneid=31&target=_blank. Domains, protocols and ports must match. - 15 - 1
    ConsoleMessage - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://vidbull.com/k1ie8l9kchme.html from frame with URL http://cdn.adnotch.com/www/delivery/afr.php?zoneid=31&target=_blank. Domains, protocols and ports must match. - 15 - 1
    ConsoleMessage - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://vidbull.com/k1ie8l9kchme.html from frame with URL http://cdn.adnotch.com/www/delivery/afr.php?zoneid=29&target=_blank. Domains, protocols and ports must match. - 15 - 1
    ConsoleMessage - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://vidbull.com/k1ie8l9kchme.html from frame with URL http://cdn.adnotch.com/www/delivery/afr.php?zoneid=29&target=_blank. Domains, protocols and ports must match. - 15 - 1
    ConsoleMessage - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://vidbull.com/k1ie8l9kchme.html from frame with URL http://cdn.adnotch.com/www/delivery/afr.php?zoneid=29&target=_blank. Domains, protocols and ports must match. - 15 - 1
    ConsoleMessage - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://vidbull.com/k1ie8l9kchme.html from frame with URL http://cdn.adnotch.com/www/delivery/afr.php?zoneid=29&target=_blank. Domains, protocols and ports must match. - 15 - 1
    ConsoleMessage - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://vidbull.com/k1ie8l9kchme.html from frame with URL http://cdn.adnotch.com/www/delivery/afr.php?zoneid=29&target=_blank. Domains, protocols and ports must match. - 15 - 1
    ConsoleMessage - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://vidbull.com/k1ie8l9kchme.html from frame with URL http://cdn.adnotch.com/www/delivery/afr.php?zoneid=29&target=_blank. Domains, protocols and ports must match. - 15 - 1
    ConsoleMessage - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://vidbull.com/k1ie8l9kchme.html from frame with URL http://cdn.adnotch.com/www/delivery/afr.php?zoneid=29&target=_blank. Domains, protocols and ports must match. - 15 - 1
    ConsoleMessage - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://highspeedtesting.com/adserver/300.html from frame with URL http://divasroom.com/adserver/300.html. Domains, protocols and ports must match. - 15 - 1
    ConsoleMessage - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://highspeedtesting.com/adserver/300x.html from frame with URL http://divasroom.com/adserver/300.html. Domains, protocols and ports must match. - 15 - 1
    ConsoleMessage - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://xp2.zedo.com/jsc/xp2/ff2.html?n=2702;c=20;s=18;d=9;w=300;h=250 from frame with URL http://divasroom.com/adserver/300.html. Domains, protocols and ports must match. - 15 - 1
    ConsoleMessage - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://cdn.adnotch.com/www/delivery/afr.php?zoneid=35&target=_blank from frame with URL http://divasroom.com/adserver/300.html. Domains, protocols and ports must match. - 15 - 1
    ConsoleMessage - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://vidbull.com/k1ie8l9kchme.html from frame with URL http://divasroom.com/adserver/300.html. Domains, protocols and ports must match. - 15 - 1
    ConsoleMessage - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://vidbull.com/k1ie8l9kchme.html from frame with URL http://nym1.ib.adnxs.com/if?enc=tD2ZBQvEwj-O3GWIECa8P5zEILByaOE_jtxliBAmvD-0PZkFC8TCP3nb6L0gRkwUCMjmCLympnU4lshTAAAAAKjyLQBNBQAAsQAAAAIAAAABbNsA7soGAAAAAQBVU0QAVVNEACwB-gA_fQAAj6QAAgUAAQIAAJIAOSc8aQAAAAA.&cnd=%21PiQwywj7gVMQgdjtBhgAIO6VGzAAOABAAEixAVCo5bcBWABgWGgAcAB4AIABAIgBAJABAZgBAaABAagBA7ABALkBtD2ZBQvEwj_BAbQ9mQULxMI_yQEsvFQJvUbvP9kBAAAAAAAA8D_gAQDqAQD1Ac3MTD4.&ccd=%21CgaxNQj7gVMQgdjtBhjulRsgAA..&udj=uf%28%27a%27%2C+379%2C+1405654584%29%3Buf%28%27c%27%2C+1360123%2C+1405654584%29%3Buf%28%27r%27%2C+14380033%2C+1405654584%29%3Bppv%2810929%2C+%271462621085427620729%27%2C+1405654584%2C+1405654644%2C+1360123%2C+445166%2C+0%2C+0%2C+10368000%29%3B&vpid=366&apid=415585&referrer=http%3A%2F%2Fdivasroom.com%2Fadserver%2F300.html&media_subtypes=1&ct=0&rsrc=2&dlo=1. Domains, protocols and ports must match. - 15 - 1
    ConsoleMessage - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://nym1.ib.adnxs.com/if?enc=tD2ZBQvEwj-O3GWIECa8P5zEILByaOE_jtxliBAmvD-0PZkFC8TCP3nb6L0gRkwUCMjmCLympnU4lshTAAAAAKjyLQBNBQAAsQAAAAIAAAABbNsA7soGAAAAAQBVU0QAVVNEACwB-gA_fQAAj6QAAgUAAQIAAJIAOSc8aQAAAAA.&cnd=%21PiQwywj7gVMQgdjtBhgAIO6VGzAAOABAAEixAVCo5bcBWABgWGgAcAB4AIABAIgBAJABAZgBAaABAagBA7ABALkBtD2ZBQvEwj_BAbQ9mQULxMI_yQEsvFQJvUbvP9kBAAAAAAAA8D_gAQDqAQD1Ac3MTD4.&ccd=%21CgaxNQj7gVMQgdjtBhjulRsgAA..&udj=uf%28%27a%27%2C+379%2C+1405654584%29%3Buf%28%27c%27%2C+1360123%2C+1405654584%29%3Buf%28%27r%27%2C+14380033%2C+1405654584%29%3Bppv%2810929%2C+%271462621085427620729%27%2C+1405654584%2C+1405654644%2C+1360123%2C+445166%2C+0%2C+0%2C+10368000%29%3B&vpid=366&apid=415585&referrer=http%3A%2F%2Fdivasroom.com%2Fadserver%2F300.html&media_subtypes=1&ct=0&rsrc=2&dlo=1 from frame with URL http://rc.rlcdn.com/281411.html?redirect=1. Domains, protocols and ports must match. - 15 - 1
    ConsoleMessage - Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains. - 15 - 1
    ConsoleMessage - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL about:blank from frame with URL https://www.facebook.com/plugins/share_button.php?app_id=172525162793917&channel=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2FbLBBWlYJp_w.js%3Fversion%3D41%23cb%3Df2ee32fd0%26domain%3Dvidbull.com%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fvidbull.com%252Ff3f898cf4%26relation%3Dparent.parent&href=http%3A%2F%2Fvidbull.com%2Fk1ie8l9kchme.html&locale=en_US&ref=.U8iWPV60qZs.share-button&sdk=joey&type=button_count. Domains, protocols and ports must match. - 15 - 1
    ConsoleMessage - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL about:blank from frame with URL https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?action=like&app_id=172525162793917&channel=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2FbLBBWlYJp_w.js%3Fversion%3D41%23cb%3Df20b111a24%26domain%3Dvidbull.com%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fvidbull.com%252Ff3f898cf4%26relation%3Dparent.parent&font=arial&href=http%3A%2F%2Fvidbull.com%2Fk1ie8l9kchme.html&layout=button_count&locale=en_US&ref=.U8iWPb73hFo.like&sdk=joey&send=false&show_faces=false&width=90. Domains, protocols and ports must match. - 15 - 1
```

Which then opens the video page which has advertisements layered over the video / etc that when clicked to close them:

```
    ConsoleMessage - Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLHtmlElement> has no method 'webkitRequestFullscreen' - 15 - 1
    ConsoleMessage - event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future. - 15 - 1
    ConsoleMessage - event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future. - 15 - 1
```

On some pages, clicking to close them, simply redirects back to the "View Video" page.  I am sure you have all experienced this type of nuissance advertising before, however since using AdBlock, I have had the pleasure of not noticing how bad things have really become.

It is imperative that any new browser system that is used for general navigation of the web have some form of blocking controls in place to prevent wacky stuff from happening, and more so, to ensure a clean user experience.

Of all the "Chrome" projects, (including CefSharp, etc), Awesomium is THE ONLY one that actually renders a page out-of-box, without endless hours of fixing stuff, only to still be no further ahead.  I have looked at EssentialObjects webbrowser control as well, however it too has limitations that even the IE WebView control has overcome.

If someone could please assist me with these issues (which really all surround taking the trash out of the browser -- ads -- not clean nice ads.... forced ads that interfere with the user experience)

Thanks in advance.

P.S.

The following code is a workaround for "click" "mousedown" "mouseup", etc ... not working ... in order to actually handle that action and navigate the browser to a new page.  If you look at the logs, you will see it is actually an error that I am using for the hack as that error seems to fire with those conditions only on a "click".

```
        If WebControl1.HasTargetURL = True And e.EventType = Awesomium.Core.WebViewEventType.ConsoleMessage And e.LineNumber = 1 Then
            WebControl1.Source = WebControl1.TargetURL
        End If
```